# Iterate all the numbers in a txt files to see if the first and last digits are the same

Tags: php

I have a `numbers.txt` file that contains many prime numbers and formatted in the following way: It begins with space, then the number, then space, then number and so on, having 8 numbers in each line, looks like this:

```
 694847539 694847551 694847557 694847611 694847633 694847663 694847669 694847693 
 694847717 694847719 694847723 694847761 694847837 694847843 694847849 694847873 
 694847891 694847893 694847903 694847911 694847921 694847947 694847999 694848013 
 694848017 694848041 694848053 694848139 694848169 694848227 694848269 694848281 
 694848307 694848311 694848379 694848397 694848437 694848457 694848461 694848503
```

How can I use PHP to open the file and iterate each number to check if the first and last digit are the same? I have the code to check if first digit and last digit are the same already:

```
$number = //need to iterate all numbers from the .txt file

$first_digit = substr($number, 0, 1); //first digit
$last_digit =  substr($number, -1);  //last digit

if($first_digit == $last_digit)
    echo $number."<br/>";
```

Comment: Read one line, and split by space with explode, which gives you an array you can iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read one line, and split by space with explode, which gives you an array you can iterate over.

> In your example there is no number having first and last digit beeing the same. So this won't output anything. You need to add such a matching example.

```
$first_and_last_equal_numbers = [];
$first_and_last_different_numbers = [];

$fh = fopen('numbers.txt', 'r') or die('Can not open file');
while($line = fgets($fh)) {
    foreach(explode(' ', $line) as $number) {
        if(!trim($number)) continue;
        if(substr($number, 0, 1) === substr($number, -1)) {
            echo $number, '<br/>';
            $first_and_last_equal_numbers[] = $number;
            continue;
        }
        $first_and_last_different_numbers[] = $number;
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: thank you. are all the numbers saved in 1 array? or every time you do the foreach it overrides the previous? Is there a way to save every number in 1 array?

Comment: I don't get your question. Each line is an array of eight numbers, and yes, will be overwritten in the next iteration (same as the line). This approach saves a lots of memory.

Comment: I'll tell you why, I just realized that for each of these numbers I need to check if this number makes a valid web address. I have www.example.com/folder/<enter_numbers_here> and check if the site is valid. So I guess I need to see if I get a valid 200 http result right? Although I do not have to store that in an array as well

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now you have two arrays. One `first_and_last_equal_numbers` and another one `first_and_last_different_numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file, just use `file_get_content()`
To have the values in an php array (separated by several type of characters) use `preg_split()`

So, u can do this :

```
   $file = "./numbers";
   $values = preg_split("/[\s\t\n\r]+/", file_get_contents($file));

   var_dump($values);
```

Then you can treat your array

```
$first = $values[0];
$last = $values[count($values) -1];
```